# A Function inside a string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I wrote some code like below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      message: "<a href='#' v-on:click='alertMe()'>alert me </a>"
  },
  methods:{
    alertMe() {
        console.log('fired')
      }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-html="message"></p>
</div>
```

I write code like this. the function is not triggering. Is there any way to trigger it.
Here is the JSfiddle link [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arafath077/tm75sqv2/1/)

Comment: This can't be done

Comment: @bert why don't you explain him why `that can't be done`?

Comment: Fair! It's not very helpful of me but I don't actually know the answer. I just know it's not possible. Presumably because it doesn't get parsed as a function call when it's compiled

Comment: this is not possible in Vue.js , you need to implement the method in clear html code as the life cycle code of vue.js as long as the events are loaded first, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: This is going to sound like I'm arguing with myself (hello other Bert) but this is possible, but not straightforward, using [Vue.compile](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile). Still likely you should take another approach.

Answer (score 3):

Value for `v-html` is not compiled by vuejs it just display content in html format like in jquery we use `.html()`, Check this docs :https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML Clearly mentioned that

> interpreted as plain HTML - data bindings are ignored

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      message: "<a href='#' onclick='alert(11)' v-on:click='alertMe()'>alert me </a>"
  },
  methods:{
     alertMe() {
        console.log('fired')
      }
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-html="message"></p>
</div>
```

You need to check for child component for this purpose

```js
var child = Vue.extend({
    template: "<div>Child Component : <a href='#' v-on:click='alertMe'>Alert</a></div>",
    methods:{
      alertMe: function(){
        console.log("Child alertMe");
        this.$parent.alertMe();
      }
    }
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-instance",
    data: {
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    components: {
        child
    },
    methods:{
      alertMe: function(){
        console.log("Parent alertMe");
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
    <child></child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Injecting `v-on:click='alertMe()'` in html is bad practise. Only standard javascript function `onClick=""` will work.

This is because Vue.js converts all vue code to standard HTML in the background, so `v-on:click=""` is converted to standard html in the background

You could use something like:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <a href="" v-on:click="alertMe"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```